# Using short string optimization appears to be slower than allocations in gcc 9.4.0

Tags: c++, g++

I'm testing the following piece of code

```
#include <string>
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    const size_t size = strtoull(argv[1], nullptr, 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    {
        std::string str;
        str.reserve(size);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {
            str += 'x';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with -O3

```
g++ string-append.cpp -O3 -o string-append
```

Now when running with parameter `15` the program appears slower then when running with parameter `16`.

```
$ time ./string-append 15

real    0m4.342s
user    0m4.342s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time ./string-append 16

real    0m3.112s
user    0m3.112s
sys     0m0.000s
```

I have verified with valgrind that: 
`15`: no allocations for the string 
`16`: 100M allocations and 100M deallocations

Using printouts I verified that:
`15`: str.c_str() returns always the same address
`16`: str.c_str() returns different address every time

Using perf I verified that `16` gives more:

- L1 cache loads
- L1 cache stores
- L1 cache misses
- branches
- branches misses
- instructions (almost twice more)

What is the reason that the code works faster for size `16`?

Compiler is gcc version 9.4.0.

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-Av3uEd/gcc-9-9.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
```

Checked on Clang13 - it does not seem to have this problem.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Quick C++ Benchmark: https://quick-bench.com/q/7uszRycpVYSiiLFgNeMv01m2PfI. Anyway, note that your entire program has no observable behavior (other than terminating the program with exit code 0). Generally, it doesn't make much sense to benchmark something that has no effects (that's why we have those _do-not-optimize_ hacks in Google Benchmark).

Comment: Program is mostly noop, Have you check assembler for the result?

Comment: In fact I removed the observable behavior code as it did not seem to affect the execution time. Apologies I did not mention that. 
@DanielLangr Thanks for the link. It does reproduce if you change standard to anything other than c++20 I checked few gcc version 9,10,11 and all seems to have the same issue.

Comment: @Jarod42 I checked the assembly and I don't see anything I would not expect. Although my assembly knowledge is limited.

Comment: @chicken-rice Note that without adding characters one-by-one, the short-string version is much faster: https://quick-bench.com/q/3pPuOQIN8zi_AsYc-qCTOndkFiI and https://quick-bench.com/q/XvnlVagoq4jZ_7n66L6D7Djh58U.

Comment: @DanielLangr Interesting observation but it does not answer my question. The constructor is implemented differently.

Comment: @Taekahn The point is not to compare gcc vs clang but "code path that seems cheaper" (sso, no allocations) with "code path that seems much more expensive" (allocations). I simply does not understand what makes the path with memory allocations faster.

Comment: @Taekahn Are you referring to [this line](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L1527)? If yes, the condition should never be true in the OP's code (capacity is 15, size is 14 in the last character insertion). So why `_M_mutate` should be called?

Comment: Well, i was gonna debug it locally, but I ran a google benchmark on the code on my machine (GCC 12.2.0), with all the same build flags you used and the String15 is more than twice as fast as String16. My machine _is_ an amd though, which could also play a factor.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the system on my local machine, even with GCC 9.4 and C++11 enabled. However, on Quick Benchmark, it gets more interesting. When the `string` object itself is allocated on the heap, than it is faster than being on the stack for the SSO case: https://quick-bench.com/q/ZaxgiIgihnHBcBaFNZCb_GWe6Bg. It seems that for some reasons, heap operations are faster than stack operations here.